# c# StreamReader, differentiate between new line, and new with with carriage return

Tags: c#, string, stream

I've dealing with a large text file (6.5GB) and I'm reading it using a `StreamReader`.

The file has portions that are separated using CRLF, however it sometimes uses just a LF.

Is there an easy way to determine if the line read in was just a newline '\n', or a carriage return with line feed '\r\n'.  The `StreamReader.ReadLine()` seems to treat them both as null or empty.

Comment: "A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n")." [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader_ReadLine). I'm not sure there is a way to change that.

Comment: What are you looking for? A list of the indexes of \n and another list of the indexes of \r\n?

Comment: Sort of.  The text file is a mess, and they are using \n in some places, and \r\n in others.  I was looking for an easy way of differentiating between the two, but I think I've got it sorted now.

Comment: Can you post your solution as the answer to this question to educate us? The only way I could thing of is to loop through the string and look for \n and put that index in a list

Answer (score 0):

you can just replace crlf and lf to cr.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"yourfile"))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"outfile")) // or any other TextWriter
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
        string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        string newLine = currentLine.Replace('\r\n','\n');
        newLine = newLine.Replace('\r','\n');
        newLine = newLine.Replace('\n','\r\n');
        writer.Write(newLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: But he didn't ask to replace the line endings